# how to properly wait for completion of NtCreateFile/etc?

Tags: driver, windows-kernel

I am using native NT API in my application to access files (NtCreateFile/etc). In order to avoid dealing with STATUS_PENDING I am using FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT flag when opening related file. So, opening file looks like this:

```
UNICODE_STRING fname = toNtUnicode(ntpath);

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa;
InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa, &fname, 0, at.handle(), NULL);

HANDLE h;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK io_status;
NTSTATUS r = NtOpenFile(&h, GENERIC_READ|SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &io_status, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE);
if (r != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    ...; // error handling
```

Unfortunately, it causes kernel to serialize all operations on given handle. I.e. if I try to execute multiple reads in parallel (using multiple threads) -- only one request will be processed at any point in time.

I could get rid of serialization:

```
HANDLE h;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK io_status;
NTSTATUS r = NtOpenFile(&h, GENERIC_READ|SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &io_status, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE);
if (r == STATUS_PENDING)
    ...; // what to do here???
```

but how exactly should I wait for completion -- `WaitForSingleObject()` on file handle? As far as I know it can change to signaled state due to many reasons -- is there any way to tell that my open file (or dir) operation completed?

Similarly, if I submit multiple reads (from multiple threads) -- how can I tell which one (if any) has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NtOpenFile` is synchronous api. it never return `STATUS_PENDING` to you. even if driver return `STATUS_PENDING` for `IRP_MJ_CREATE` i/o sub-system will be wait for *IRP* complete

https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/parse.c#L1404

so you never need check for `STATUS_PENDING` after `NtOpenFile` and never need wait (and in principle we can not wait here - we yet not have file handle -so can not wait on it or bind it to say *IOCP*. we not pass any event or another callback mechanism for `NtOpenFile`)

Comment: Strange... I swear I observed STATUS_UPDATE when opening directories. I'll test it again. Meanwhile, about other operations -- am I supposed to wait on that event I pass to NtReadFile? If yes, then I don't really need SYNCHRONIZE flag, right?

Comment: What about NtClose() -- is it guaranteed to be synchronous? Also, may I assume that everything said about NtXXX functions equally apply to corresponding ZwXXX functions (if called in user-mode)?

Comment: @C.M. the `ZwOpenFile` and `ZwClose` is **synchronous** api by design. it **never** return `STATUS_PENDING`. the *Nt* and *Zw* functions - is alias in user mode. this is the same function (both names point to the same address)

Comment: Thank you. So, is there are any reason to use SYNCHRONIZE flag when opening file/directory?

Comment: @C.M. - your question say about you nothing understand at all. `SYNCHRONIZE` this is **access** right. are you need use `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_[NO]NALERT` - this depend from your targets - are you want have synchronous or asynchronous io on file.

Comment: I need asynchronous I/O on file/dir. I assumed I'll have to wait (on file handle) for related requests to complete (when they return STATUS_PENDING). But since NtOpen/Close functions are always synchronous and NtRead/Write take HEVENT (that I can use to wait for completion) -- I don't need to wait on file handle at all. Hence the question -- do I really need SYNCHRONIZE flag?

Comment: @C.M. wait on file handle is always mistake. in case asynchronous file handle and api - you need or wait on event(the worst variant) or bind handle to IOCP or use APC completion. are NtRead/Write will be synchronous or asynchronous depend from - are you using `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_[NO]NALERT` option when you create or open file. if you need asynchronous api - simply not use this options. the `SYNCHRONIZE` flag you really not need in this case. however if you set it - **nothing** changed. and ZwOpenFile/ZwCreateFile/ZwClose - is **synchronous** api.

Comment: Can I assume that if given NtXXX function doesn't take HEVENT then it is synchronous? (e.g. NtQueryInformationFile/NtDeleteFile)

Comment: @C.M. - sorry, i not understand your last question about `NtXXX function`

Comment: Accidentally pressed Enter mid-typing. you are too fast :)

Comment: @C.M. - yes. you correct. this is **synchronous** api. all **asyncronous** api have next signature : `IN HANDLE  FileHandle,
    IN HANDLE  Event OPTIONAL,
    IN PIO_APC_ROUTINE  ApcRoutine OPTIONAL,
    IN PVOID  ApcContext OPTIONAL,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK  IoStatusBlock`

Comment: @C.M. - i recommended for you found wrk src and look in it. also read [`IoIsOperationSynchronous`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548443(v=vs.85).aspx)  - *if the IRP_SYNCHRONOUS_API flag is set in the IRP, the operation is synchronous. This flag is set for operations, such as ZwQueryInformationFile and ZwSetInformationFile, that are always synchronous, even when performed on a file object that was opened for asynchronous I/O.*

Comment: I looked around ntoskrnl repo you've referenced -- but unfortunately it doesn't contain code for ZwQueryInformationFile/etc. I.e. I have no idea what these functions call.

Comment: @C.M. - look for example here - https://github.com/markjandrews/wrk-v1.2/tree/master/base/ntos/io/iomgr . all main NtXXX for files here exist. look also `IopSynchronousApiServiceTail` and from where it called. for open/create file look `IopParseDevice`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! I don't need to ask stupid questions anymore :)